# python list_iterator class not defined

Tags: python

I am trying the following:

```
>>> i = iter([1,2,3])
>>> print(type(i))
<class 'list_iterator'>
>>> print(type(i).mro())
[<class 'list_iterator'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> j = list_iterator()
```

and the last lines gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pru/ML/stepik/examples module2/iterators.py", line 10, in <module>
    j = list_iterator()
NameError: name 'list_iterator' is not defined
```

How come it is not defined? Wouldn't interpreter look for name 'list_iterator' in 'object' namespace?

Comment: Because it's not one of the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) that are exposed to you; you'd have to access it via `type(i)` instead, but what were you hoping to do with it?

Comment: by j = list_iterator() I was trying to create an instance of a list_iterator class. I am just playing around while learning Python.

Comment: But *to what end*, what were you going to do with j? What values did you expect to get from iterating over it?

Comment: nothing, just curiosity

Comment: so, how can I create an instance of this class? list_iterator is a class, right?

Comment: You already know that: by passing a list to iter.

Comment: why can't I do it directly by j = list_iterator()? what is the keyword I have to google?

Comment: Again, because it's not exposed to you - there are a lot of types in Python that aren't, especially views and iterators.

Answer (score 2):

*"Wouldn't interpreter look for name 'list_iterator' in 'object' namespace?"* that's not how it works. `object` is a class, not a namespace, and `list_iterator` is a subclass of `object`, but that doesn't mean it must be accessable to us.

In most cases, you don't need to use `list_iterator`, that's why it's not exposed to us, but if you *really* need it, you can use it by defining it like so:

```py
list_iterator = type(iter([]))
```

Comment: so, there are classes that are actually defined but not accessible?

Comment: @prupru yes, another example is `NoneType`. This is not exclusive to built-ins, you can define a type in a file A.py, define a function that returns an instance of that class in B.py, and import that function in C.py, now in C.py you have an instance of a class you don't have access to (as long as you only import B.py and not A.py)

Answer (score -1):

```
i = iter([1,2,3])
print(i)
print(type(i))
print(type(i).mro())
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
list_iterator = type(i)
print(list_iterator)
```

**> <list_iterator object at 0x7fa1763262b0> <class 'list_iterator'>

> [<class 'list_iterator'>, <class 'object'>] 1 2 3 <class
> **> 'list_iterator'>****